# youtube data api v3 : adding a complaint

Tags: ios, youtube-data-api

I'm migrating from **YouTube-data-v3-api**  to **YouTube-data-v2-api** for an **iOS** app. How do I add a complaint about a uploaded YouTube video? I want to add this(link below) functionality in **YouTube-data-v3-api**, https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_complaints.
Please do suggest how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do that in v3 api.

According to the Video documentation(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), the only way to interact with a Video that does not belong to the authenticated user in the v3 api is to give it a rating.